# Throwing an exception after retrying a block of code

Tags: java

Is it correct, safe and sane to throw an exception after a successful retry? Which programming principle is violated in this example?

```
class B {
    private int total;

    public void add(int amount) throws Exception {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new Exception("Amount is negative");
        }
        total += amount;
    }
}

class A {
    public B b = new B();

    public void addToB(int amount) throws Exception {
        try {
            b.add(amount);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                b.add(-amount);
            } catch (Exception ex2) {
            }
            throw new Exception("Amount was negative. It was inverted and then added.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you throw the second exception? Should it not be inside catch?

Comment: Well, this is a solution from someone else. I am trying to argue that it is wrong. There is a smallest solution, but it is not enough to say this one is a bad practice. The second exception is to "inform" that the method has inverted the amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `code` is working but  since you are calling a `addToB() method`  which `throws exception` inside a `catch block` you must implement another `try-catch block within try-catch block`. and at the end you are `throwing a exception` even after having so many `try-catch blocks` which is not good since the `exceptions` if not handled can cause `problems` and its very bad `practise` to `throw exception` if the method was `success`. i see that you need the user to know what happened inside the `method`, you can `return` a `string` from the 
method which will tell the user what happened `inside the method`.

ex: -

```
public String addToB(int amount){
       String msg = "";
        try{
            b.add(amount);
            msg ="successful";
        }catch(Exception ex){
            try{
                b.add(-amount);
            }catch(Exception ex2){
            }
           msg= "Amount was negative. It was inverted and then added.";
        }
 return msg;
    }
```

even this is not the best practise bt you might need check this.

Comment: Thanks! "its very bad practise to throw exception if the method was success" It is what I need. I am looking for a reference to argue that it is a bad practise, do you know any?

Comment: you dont need any refference for that , by the way if the method was success and the instance where you are calling the method didnt handle the exception even though it says success , wil stop the program.

Comment: Hahaha. That's right, it is an evident truth. Maybe I am just losing my time trying to convince them. But it is nice to know that someone else feels the same way: the method addToB has bad programing practices and I don't need a reference to demonstrate it. If you need a reference, then you don't have programming skills.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few sound principles that you are violating.

1. Throwing `java.lang.Exception` is bad in such situations (or in general), even if you are writing *toy* code. You should consider using a `RuntimeException`. The idea is pretty simple. You know nothing about the `amt` until you run the program. If a user or client of this code provides negative argument, then it an unexpected argument only to be known at runtime. Do not promote the [Pokemon exception handling anti-pattern](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).
2. You are utilizing the [baklava code](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/27/baklav-code/) pattern. This should be avoided.
3. The more serious error you are committing is doing the thing anyway exceptionally or not. Here's a use of your classes:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = null;
       try {
           a = new A();
           a.addToB(10); // no exception here, total should be 10
           a.addToB(-10); 
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // exception here, but the total should be 20, or not?
           System.out.println(a.getTotalFromB());
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, in this case, the value of `total` is `20` **even when an exception was thrown**! Almost always, exceptions should be used to signal exceptional conditions where the *expected* things do not happen. This, to me, is a serious violation.

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* to do this, but this is a bad idea for three reasons:

- You're using [exceptions as control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/54997).  This is an antipattern which is to be avoided.
- You're throwing `Exception`.  If this is truly exceptional behavior, then you should look to create your own [checked] exception type.
- You're *catching* `Exception` in that block.  If `b` is `null` then you're not guaranteed that the input was invalid at all.

Let's start with the flow.

In this scenario, it doesn't make immediate sense why a negative value is considered exceptional enough to *recover* from, which is what the checked exception implies.

Effectively, if the first attempt seems to fail with a negative number, the idea is to try it again by negating the negative, resulting in a positive number.

Something like this can be mitigated in several ways, depending on what the negative value means to the business:

- Throwing multiple exceptions (least preferred)
- Silently drop it, but log the value passed in (less preferred)
- Throw an **unchecked** exception and do not require its callers to catch it (preferred)

With my preference, the code above would look like this:

```
public void add(int amount) {
    if(amount < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount may not be negative");
    total += amount;
}
```

This would put the onus of ensuring that the input is correct and appropriate for this method on the developer as opposed to the application.  Unit tests here would go a long way to ensure the behavior that you want.

Now, to throwing `Exception`:  `Exception` is *checked* meaning that everyone has to catch it or declare it to be thrown, which is unpleasant to code.

Checked exceptions should be reserved for something that the *user* can do to recover from (for instance, `FileNotFoundException` - user should be sure that the file path is correct).

Lastly - you should *not* be catching `Exception`.  That's too broad of an exception to catch, considering that `b` may be `null`.